I created this code, and it showed the following error: 'TS2604: JSX element type 'ReactToPrint' does not have any construct or call signatures
import * as React from "react";
import { useRef } from "react";
//import parse from 'html-react-parser';
import ReactToPrint from "react-to-print";

import { IInputs } from "../generated/ManifestTypes";

import '../css/AppStyles.css';

interface IHTML2PrintComponentProps {
    appContext: ComponentFramework.Context<IInputs>
}

const HTML2PrintComponent: React.FC<IHTML2PrintComponentProps> = ({ appContext }) => {
    const componentRef = useRef(null);

    return(
        <React.Fragment>

            <ReactToPrint //(The error appears on this "reactToPrint")

                trigger={ () => <button id="btnImprimitPDF">{ appContext.parameters.ButtonText.raw }</button> }
                content={ () => componentRef.current }
            />
            <div className="pagebreak full-table">
                {/* { document.title = appContext.parameters.DefaultFilename.raw? } */}
                <div ref={ componentRef }>
                    {/* { parse(appContext.parameters.CustomCss.raw?) } */}
                </div>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default HTML2PrintComponent;

I've tried some tutorials, but none have yielded significant results. The options I found talk about the constructor, but in cases quite different from this one. If you could help me, I'd appreciate it

Which react-to-print version are you using ? Because in v3 changelog they state "ReactToPrint removed. Use useReactToPrint".

Try again, here is the latest version 3.0.2 of react-to-print:
import { useReactToPrint } from 'react-to-print';
const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => componentRef?.current,
    documentTitle: 'title',
    onAfterPrint: () => {}
});


I modified the import and added the constant inside the HTML2PrintComponent function, but besides the existing error, another error appeared above "content": Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'content' does not exist in type 'UseReactToPrintOptions'.ts(2353).

@DanielVitor can you provide the code you edited?
